# Resource route show route to index

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a resource route:

```
Route::resource('product', 'ProductController@index', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'destroy']]);
```

The index lists all items in the database:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('product', ['products' => Product::all()]);
}
```

and at the moment the show just echos the ID:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return 'Show '.$id;
}
```

if I go to url/product the correct data shows up.
if I go to url/product/{ProductID} the index page shows up... not the echo of the id.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Do you know if I have done something silly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the action name after the controller

```
 Route::resource('product', 'ProductController', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'destroy']]);
   // -------------------------------------^
```

When using `RESTful Resource Controllers`, we only need to pass the controller name and it will stub the action itself.

source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Comment: Changing to echo would have the same result... Tried it though out of curiosity. Issue persists.